# Creating circle using QGIS

Tags: qgis, editing

In QGIS I have added the shape layer to the toolbar, but I can never seem to select the shapes.

How do I create a simple circle?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Create a new polygon layer and select it
2. Enable Editing Mode
3. Draw your shapes

[image]